# MyQuery error: "null | Unknown column in 'where clause'"

Tags: java, mysql

This is for my senior project. Please keep in mind that I'm still a beginner.

So I want to create a search app where the user will choose a 'speciality' from a JComboBox and once they click 'Search', the app will retrieve data from MySQL database and display it in a JTable.

Since I'm not a pro at programming I followed some tutorials and I'm stuck on this error:

> Unknown column 'Architecture' in 'where clause'

'Architecture' is one of the options in the JComboBox but I think SQL reads it as a column although it is a row!

this is my Query:

```
public class MyQuery {

   public Connection getConnection(){
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydata?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "1110");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Query.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return con;
    }

    public ArrayList<Applications> getData(String speciality){

   ArrayList<Applications> list = new ArrayList<Applications>();
   Connection con = getConnection();
   Statement st;
   ResultSet rows;

   try {
   st = con.createStatement();

   rows = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mydb.applications WHERE speciality LIKE " + speciality);

   Applications applications;
   while(rows.next()){
   applications = new Applications(
   rows.getInt("id"),
   rows.getString("name"),
   rows.getString("nationality"),
   rows.getString("speciality"),
   rows.getString("experience")
   );

   list.add(applications);
   }

   } catch (SQLException ex) {
   Logger.getLogger(MyQuery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
   return list;
   }
}
```

&

```
        JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search...\n");
    btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            MyQuery mq = new MyQuery();
            ArrayList<Applications> list = mq.getData((String)comboBox_searchSp.getSelectedItem());
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
            model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"ID","Name","Nationality","Speciality","Experience"});
            Object[] row = new Object[5];
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                row[0] = list.get(i).getName();
                row[1] = list.get(i).getNationality();
                row[2] = list.get(i).getSpeciality();
                row[3] = list.get(i).getExperience();
                model.addRow(row);
            }
            table.setModel(model);

        }

            public void BindCombo(){

            MyQuery mq = new MyQuery();
            Connection con =  mq.getConnection();
            Statement st;
            ResultSet rows;

            try {
                st = con.createStatement();
                rows = st.executeQuery("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM mydb.applications");
                while(rows.next()){
                    comboBox_searchSp.addItem(rows.getInt(1));
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AdminPage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            }

    });
```

Comment: So... why is this "severe"? Because you waited until the last minute?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is in your SQL query syntax:

```
rows = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mydb.applications WHERE speciality LIKE " + speciality);
```

should be:

```
rows = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mydb.applications WHERE speciality LIKE '" + speciality+"'");
```

Answer (score 1):

An even better solution is to use a `PreparedStatement` -- then you won't get into trouble if one of your specialties was `Being "cool"`, even though it contains a quote character.

Prepared statements also protect you against SQL injection attacks.

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM mydb.applications WHERE speciality LIKE ?");
ps.setString(1, specialty);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put quotes around the input:

```
rows = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mydb.applications WHERE speciality LIKE '" + speciality + "'");
```